# Why is my box shadow elliptical as I would a circle?

Tags: html, css

I'm new at web developpement and I'm learning html and css with css battles. I'm stucked on the 3rd level beacause I'm using box shadow to make these outer circles but I can't understand why this is making this weird elliptical effect. Can someone help me please ?

Here is my code :

```css
body
{
position:relative;
background: #6592CF;  
display: flex;
align-items:center;
justify-content: center;
}
.inner-circle
{
position: absolute;
width:50px;
aspect-ratio:1;
background: #EEB850;
box-shadow: 0 0 0 50px #243D83,
        0 0 0 100px #6592CF;
border-radius: 100%;
}
.square
{
position: absolute;
width: 300px;
height: 150px;
background: #243D83;
z-index:-1;
}
```

```html
<div class="inner-circle"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
```

Thanks for answers.

Comment: That's the `square` background

Comment: This isn't to do with the div with class square particularly - you get a sort of squashed circle even if that isn't present so you may like to take it out of your snippet so we don't get sidetracked.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `border` and `outline` properties for that. Just change `.inner-circle` styles like this:

```
.inner-circle {
  position: relative;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #eeb850;
  /* box-shadow: 0 0 0 25px #243d83, 0 0 0 100px #6592cf; */
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 50px solid #243d83;
  outline: 50px solid #6592cf;
}
```